# Using string split in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I am attempting to read in from a txt file strings that are very similar to the following:

YXCZ0000292=TRUE

or

THS83777930=FALSE

I need to use string split to collect a serial number and put it into a variable I can use later as well as use the true or false portion of the string to set a check box.  The serial numbers will never be the same and the TRUE or FALSE portion can be random.  Anyone have a good way to handle this one?

Comment: What have you already tried (i.e. do you have a _specific_ problem)?

Comment: Please give more instruction/details before giving downvotes for new users. This question is not a too bad question for a new user I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any `string` called `line`, you should be able to do

```
var parts = line.Split('=');
var serial = parts[0];
var boolean = bool.Parse(parts[1]);
```

I'm thinking that should work as needed.

Comment: currently, you have "TRUE" or "FALSE" __string__ value in your "boolean" variable. You should use Boolean.Parse

Comment: Good point, I'll throw that in (I overlooked that fact that he wanted to use them with a checkbox).

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "THS83777930=FALSE";
var parts = s.Split( '=' );

// error checking here, i.e., make sure parts.Length == 2
var serial = parts.First();
var booleanValue = parts.Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ss = String.Split('=');
Console.WriteLine(ss[0]); //YXCZ0000292
Console.WriteLine(ss[1]); //TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text file contains only one serial and value:

```
string text=File.ReadAllText("c:\filePath.txt");
string[] parts=text.split("=");
```

Now parts[0] is the serial and parts[1] is the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above should work correctly. Once you need to set some checkbox value, you should have a boolean value parsed. See [Boolean.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx)

```
string s = "YXCZ0000292=TRUE";
string[] parts = s.Split('=');
string serial = parts[0];
bool value = Boolean.Parse(parts[1].ToLower());
```

to set checkbox value just use **checked**

```
checkbox.checked = value
```

Comment: You don't the call the `ToLower` since `Boolean.Parse` works in a case-insentive manner.